# How to install Facebook pixel event code in a php button?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-pixel

So I have a simple PHP share button fo facebook and I want to add pixel event code in it that tracks the button when it's clicked

Here is the code for the button:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1"> 
                                    <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-block btn-social c-btn-square c-btn-uppercase btn-md btn-facebook" href="{{$facebook_link}}">
                                         <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i> Share on Facebook
```

Where should I exactly put the code for the event which is:

```js
<script>
  fbq('track', 'SubmitApplication');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome. You must handle event when button click.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var facebookButton = document.querySelector('a.btn-facebook');
facebookButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    fbq('track', 'SubmitApplication');
});
</script>
```